# Generating list of iterations on own output in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, unfold

Sorry for what seems like a basic question, but I could not find it anywhere. In Python 2, I would like to apply a 1-variable function to its own output storing the list of all steps, i.e. if f(x) returns x*x then iterating from 2, i need to get

`[2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, ...]`

Ideally, I would need to pass in my function `f`, the first input `1`, and the number of iterations I would like to keep.

I guess this is, in some sense, the opposite of `reduce` and somewhat similar to `unfold` from functional programming.

A naive way to do this is to write

`out = [2]
 for x in xrange(5):
     out.append(f(out[-1]))`

What is a good Pythonic way to do this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: If your first input is `1`, the output is [1, 1, 1, ...], right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a "[Generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)". For example,

```
def f(x, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield x
        x = x * x

l = list(f(2, 5))

print(l)             # [2, 4, 16, 256, 65536]
```

Or

```
def f(x):
    while True:
        yield x
        x = x * x

for v in f(2):
    if v > 100000:
        break
    print(v),        # 2 4 16 256 65536
```

Comment: BTW, use `xrange()` for Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally, I would need to pass in my function f, the first input 1, and
>   the number of iterations I would like to keep.

Here is an unfold function that accepts a function, a starting value, and an iteration count.

```
def unfold(function, start, iterations):
    results = []
    for _ in range(iterations):
        results.append(start)
        start = function(start)

    return results
```

Which you can use as expected:

```
>>> print unfold(lambda x: x*x, 2, 5)
[2, 4, 16, 256, 65536]
```

Comment: I don't understand how is this better than my code sample in the question, except that you abstracted this away into a stand alone function?

Comment: Also you probably want to use xrange instead of range.